# Add an extra element to Wordpress nav items with children

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a nested dropdown. On elements that have children, I would like to add a chevron beside the link text. The current HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="primary-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has- 
    children menu-item-59">
        <a href="#">Europe</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to use an add_filter hook to turn this markup into this:

```
<ul class="primary-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has- 
    children menu-item-59">
        <div>
          <a href="#">Europe</a>
          <img src="chevron.svg">
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I was hoping to find a filter that would return me an array of menu items. If the menu item has the class of 'menu-item-has-children' I would like to change the HTML within the item.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using CSS to insert that image?

Comment: _“I was hoping to find a filter that would return me an array of menu items.”_ - displaying a menu structure in WP is generally done using the [`Walker_Nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) class. You can check the source to see which filters its method apply in which places; if there isn’t one that can help achieve what you want, then you can also create your own class based on this one, and overwrite specific methods with your own coding. (But then you might have to modify which class it uses explicitly in your template.)

Comment: @04FS I would love to, but I can't. The problem is that in the mobile menu, clicking the image will open the dropdown but clicking the link will open the page. If I use css to add the image as a psuedo element, I cannot attach a click event to the image. I will take a look at the walker_nav_menu. I was looking through the 2020 theme for inspiration and was wondering what that was all about....

Comment: _“clicking the image will open the dropdown”_ - that must be something you added via JavaScript then? Then you might as well insert the images via JavaScript on the client side as well, because without they’d have no function anyway.

Comment: Ok, good point! Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [walker_nav_menu_start_el](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/walker_nav_menu_start_el/) hook.
Use the actual name of your menu or remove the condition - is_nav_menu( 'Mobile Menu' ).

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'parent_menu_dropdown', 10, 4 );
function parent_menu_dropdown( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {

    if ( is_nav_menu( 'Mobile Menu' ) && ! empty( $item->classes ) && in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes ) ) {
        return $item_output . '<img src="chevron.svg">';
    }

    return $item_output;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Man I've tried running this in my code which is similar, but it seems to have no effect, do you have to make changes somewhere else aswell?